# Is there an aspect already written and tested well for TRACE logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, aspectj, logback

I am refactoring a legacy application where the actual application is scattered in between lot of logging statements. I could immediately benefit by removing TRACE level logging (method entered/exited). However this has proven to be useful many times while debugging an app while integration testing etc. So I am wondering if there is already a working and proven (being used for a while) aspect written for this? I've gone though some online posts but they seem to simple enough (and not sure if they have ever been really used) to be used for real project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout aspects from "AspectJ in Action" (sources can be downloaded from http://manning.com/laddad2). I have used very close variations of aspects from chapter 10 on real projects.

Comment: Thank you. Read that nicely written book. If the variations are to use the aspects in real world projects then can you pls make the new aspects downloadable

Comment: I am glad you liked the book. The variations were mostly about format and additional info (which user is accessing the method, for example, grabbed from a thread-local), so don't really affect the core of the aspect. Also, they are in commercial projects so can't provide sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`@Loggable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-loggable.html) annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/), together with a built-in AspectJ aspect:

```
@Loggable(Loggable.TRACE)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

It logs through [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/), which you can redirect to your own logging facility like, say, log4j.