# Java, how to trace functions called

Tags: java, trace

I want to trace the beginning [& ending] of functions called in Java, like the following code:

```
    public void foo() {
  System.out.println("begin of foo()");
  ...
  System.out.println("e-n-d of foo()");
 }
```

But maintaining of the dump code `System.out.println` is something tedious and error-prone, for there may be tens of thounds of function in an class.

Any good idea can ease this work? I don't want dump statements all over the file.

Implementation of both or one of the beginning & ending traces is perferd.

But, if impossible, recordings of that the function has been called is also helpful. I mean not care the exact beginnig and ending, just tell that the function has been called.

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe AspectJ is intended for things like this. It will modify your compiled byte code with hooks that you specify. Never used it, but I think that's something it does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653013/is-there-an-aspect-already-written-and-tested-well-for-trace-logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is the one you've chose.

An easy replacement for the `System.out` calls would be using a logging framework. Then you could switch the information on and off according to a selected "logging level"

More sophisticated solutions would use aspect oriented programming techniques (provide by AspectJ, for instance), but this puts you on a steep learning curve.

Maybe a tool-based a approach fits your needs: so called "profilers" can "instrument" your code and report exactly which method was called during a run.

Comment: The later is the most desirable I think, as I doubt such behaviour would be desirable in production code, and why re-invent the wheel with AOP. Something like TPTP for Eclipse should be able to give a dump of all function calls and even timings. The output's probably going to be in some binary format, but that may be ok given that it's likely to be massive.

Comment: I won't attach any code to these functions, for that's not my code, and that will need a lot of work. AspectJ may work. But what a "profilers" is, also, what a tool-based approach is, can you give an example or an link. That will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CurtainDog: Thanks a lot. Indeed I need one of languages related solution.

Comment: @user435657 - what's your intention? A profiler (like [TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/)) always comes with a report viewer, they are *designed* to support analysis tasks. You don't have to write a single line of code - just start the application from the profiler and it records all method calls.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach would be using [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace/pages/UserGuide) - it is kind of similar to AspectJ but can attach to a running java application and apply the logging code on-the-fly (it can also detach from the application, removing all the injected code but leaving the app running as it was before using **BTrace**)

In order to use **BTrace** you would write a simple tracing script which is POJO annotated with **BTrace** annotations (and some restrictions regarding what is possible to use to avoid crashing the target application).

In this case the the script would look like this:

```
@BTrace public class FooTracer {
  @OnMethod(clazz="Bar", method="foo")
  public static void onEntry() {
    println("begin of foo()");
  }

  @OnMethod(clazz="Bar", method="foo", location=@Location(Kind.RETURN))
  public static void onExit() {
    println("end of foo");
  }
}
```

There are many more things you can do with **BTrace** - just refer to the user guide and examples. Nominally, it is console application but there is integration into [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) making the experience of working with **BTrace** more pleasant.

Answer (score 2):

If there are lots of methods to log, **AOP** could be used. For example, aspectJ.

Comment: 你好！Should I append aditional code to those functions if using aspectJ.

Comment: No need to write additional code in Java. Write log code in aspectJ, then mix up aspectJ code to Java byte code, the process is called 'wave'. An simple example: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2002/jw-0301-aspect2.html?page=2

Answer (score 0):

You could use log4j for this:

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                      log4jExample.class.getName());

public void loggedMethod() {

 log.info("begin of loggedMethod()");
  ...
 log.info("e-n-d of loggedMethod()");
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I mean get ride of suppling any addition code to log/record that the function has been called.