# How to get Java Call Stack of a running application

Tags: java, debugging, callstack

I am working on very huge java web based application. As there is no proper logging done while development so its very difficult for me to put break point and debug the app as i dont know execution order. Is there any mechanism to get complete Call Stack of the the running java application after I perform some actions.

I searched it on net for long time but cannot came to concrete solution. Please suggest me if something is there for it. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706292/java-determining-current-call-stack-for-diagnostic-purposes

Comment: @sns Did you find anyway to find the entire stack of the application flow in the runtime?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Method 1: Use jstack utility from command line (part of the JDK distro).

Method 2: Send signal 3 to the java process, it will dump stack traces on stdout.

Method 3: Call Thread.getAllStackTraces () from within application:

```
public class StackTraceDumper
{
    public static dumpAllStackTraces ()
    {
        for (Map.Entry <Thread, StackTraceElement []> entry: 
            Thread.getAllStackTraces().entrySet ())
        {
            System.out.println (entry.getKey ().getName () + ":");
            for (StackTraceElement element: entry.getValue ())
                System.out.println ("\t" + element);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `StackTraceDumper.dumpAllStackTraces()` where you need to dump stack traces.

Comment: Can u please suggest me where to write this stackTrace() code snippet?? I want to write a single code snippet that can be used everywhere.

Comment: `jstack` does not ship as part of the JRE (at least not in version 7) it does however ship as part of the JDK.

Answer (score 6):

`Thread.dumpStack()` 
          Prints a stack trace of the current thread to the standard error stream.
`Thread.getAllStackTraces()`
          Returns a map of stack traces for all live threads.
`Thread.getStackTrace()`
          Returns an array of stack trace elements representing the stack dump of this thread.

Comment: Can u please suggest me where to write this stackTrace() code snippet?? I want to write a single code snippet that can be used everywhere

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [`Throwable.getStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29). Just create a new `Throwable`; you don't actually have to `throw` it.

Comment: This will dump stack trace for one thread only, the current thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger a stack dump via pressing *Ctrl+Break*, or sending a signal 3 (on Unix-based systems). Note that you'll get a stack trace *per-thread*. This will go to *standard error*, so make sure your logging is capturing this.

You can do this programatically via

```
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> m = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
```

Here's [more info](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/synodinos/archive/2007/08/the_taming_of_t.html) on getting and analysing stack traces.

As you've noted, BTrace is another possibility. Here's [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683514/12960) on using it.

Comment: I want to find complete call stack when i perform some action from the application button e.g. (on Register Patient). Do u know about BTrace what is it :(???

Comment: I can't really advise other than to refer you to an SO answer (see above)

Comment: Can u please suggest me where to write this stackTrace() code snippet?? I want to write a single code snippet that can be used everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options:

- Run it in a debugger, and pause all threads, then you can inspect them
- Use VisualVM to connect to the running processes and trigger a thread dump.  It comes with the JDK.
- Use jstack on the command line, to dump threads.

Add some basic logging to your code:

```
new RuntimeException().printStackTrace();
```

That will pring a static trace to stderr

Comment: This will print stack trace for one thread only, the current thread.

Comment: Yes, the code line print the current thread.  The other examples will print all thread stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some AOP tool like AspectJ to capture these values and log? You can use execution() point cut along with after() advice. For non production deployment you can log all the method calls along with passed values and returned value. This will be too much overhead for production env. For that you can just store the passed values (Object args[] as you get in AspectJ advice) in local variable and only log it in case of exception. But even in that case there will be some performance penalty as primitive values will be boxed to be passed as Object[] to your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case people are reading this post to find out how to get the class or classes of the stack of the current thread:

```java
StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
String smallStack = "Calling classes: " + System.lineSeparator() + stack[2] + System.lineSeparator() + stack[3];
```

This will get the stack for the current thread.

- `stack[0]` will be the getStackTrace call itself.
- `stack[1]` will be the line of code where you are working.
- So `stack[2]` and `stack[3]` are the first 'interesting' stack elements.