# TeamCity - retry after a build timeout

Tags: teamcity

We have a TeamCity build that runs end to end tests, and every once in a while, for an unclear reason, it gets stuck.
So I set a timeout after a certain amount of time and I want it to automatically run again after the timeout occurs.

I know there's a 'Retry Build Trigger' but I want it to retry only on timeout and not on every failure.

Any suggestions?

Extra information that might help:

- The result appears as 'Execution timeout (new)'
- When a timeout occurs the build log writes 'The build %Build-Name% {builId=63608} has been running for more than 100 minutes. Terminating...'

Comment: what is the build doing that causes it to hang? you can look at the Build Log to see what it last did/is doing. it may be indicating a real issue

Comment: It's under investigation, in the meanwhile we are looking for a workaround, the build log is not really informative:

`[03:07:43]*Some print to console*
[05:30:27]The build %Build-Name% {builId=63608} has been running for more than 100 minutes. Terminating...`

Comment: attach your debugger to the test runner.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: what is TC running when it hangs? not just `end to end tests` <-- what *sort* of tests, who is running the tests (which application or test runner)

Comment: We're using TestNG to run E2E tests on android devices using Appium (written in Java).

Comment: ok. suggest using eclipse to attach to the running process or get the callstack/threads of the test runner to see whats going on. eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705451/how-to-get-java-call-stack-of-a-running-application