# Java logging method calls?

Tags: java, debugging

Is there any tools that can be used to log all method calls from running java application?

eg.

```
String str = "...";
String anotherString = str.trim();
```

should log something like this:

```
..method call trim() from class java.lang.String
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an aspect already written and tested well for TRACE logging.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653013/is-there-an-aspect-already-written-and-tested-well-for-trace-logging)

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a profiler.

Some popular profilers are:
[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) which has different ways to do method call recording, both on CPU and memory level.

[VisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) is another one

Many IDE's (I know Netbeans and Eclipse) have their own profilers you can use.

Comment: It should be noted that the profiler in VisualVM (which is more than just a profiler) is based on the Netbeans Profiler (but quite reduced in complexity and with a slightly smaller feature set).

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and write advice that intercepts method calls. There is an example of how to do this "tracing" logging [in the programmer guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/examples-development.html#tracing-using-aspects).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@Loggable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-loggable.html) annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/), which wraps all methods you want to debug with a simple logging mechanism:

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

It logs through [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).