# Record every method execution

Tags: java

Is there any way that I can log / record / monitor / view every execution of a method inside of a Java program.

For example:

```
12:30:12 someMethod("argument")
12:30:12 anotherMethos(1, 2, 3)
12:30:13 finalMethod("invalidInputHere1234")
```

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://extranet.ipl.be/OOMADB/document/IPL_cours/COO/logging-at-loadingTime.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823557/java-logging-method-calls & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653013/is-there-an-aspect-already-written-and-tested-well-for-trace-logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy answer: modify the method, and insert logging statements.

Somewhat more complex answer, which works even if you can't modify the method: look into aspect-based programming.

Comment: I want to trace hundreds of methods so can't really change every single one of them. Is there not a way of monitoring the execution of a Java program to see the methods being run? I know that I can use NetBeans to track a variable's value - what about which methods have been executed?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://mathewjhall.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/tracing-java-method-execution-with-aspectj/)

Answer (score 2):

Without modifying the code you could use a debugger or profiler that is able to record any state change, like the [Chronon time travelling debugger](http://www.chrononsystems.com/products/chronon-time-travelling-debugger).

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://github.com/taobao/TProfiler

Answer (score 1):

You can record your program and then play it with [Chronon](http://www.chrononsystems.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@Loggable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-loggable.html) annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/), which wraps all methods you want to debug with a simple logging mechanism:

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

It logs through [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).