# Is there a way to catch when any JPopupMenu is shown?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to log every time any `JPopupMenu` is shown (visible).

I tried to catch via AWT Events, but `MouseEvent` does not provide `JPopupMenu` due `JPopupMenu` might still be generating and not yet visible

I wonder if there some trick so I can catch when any `JPopupMenu` is shown without adding listeners to each `JPopupMenu` currently used in an App

Comment: Individually, probably not. What might be better is to have a factory or builder which can produce a `JPopupMenu` which you have control of, from which you can then monitor yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like focus is given to the `JRootPane` whenever a `JPopupMenu` is shown. You can listen for this event by using a `KeyboardFocusManager`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.beans.*;

public class PopupListener extends JPanel
{
    JPopupMenu menu;

    public PopupListener()
    {
        menu = new JPopupMenu();
        menu.add( new JMenuItem( "Cut" ) );
        menu.add( new JMenuItem( "Copy" ) );
        menu.add( new JMenuItem( "Paste" ) );

        MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger())
                {
                    menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                    menu.setInvoker( e.getComponent() );
                }
            }
        };

        addMouseListener( ml );

        JButton button = new JButton( "Button" );
        button.setComponentPopupMenu( menu );
        //button.addMouseListener( ml );
        add(button);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PopupListener");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new PopupListener());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
            .addPropertyChangeListener("focusOwner", new PropertyChangeListener()
        {
            public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent e)
            {
                Container container = (Container)e.getNewValue();

                if (container != null
                &&  container instanceof JRootPane)
                {
                    System.out.println( "Popup Shown" );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Don't know if this is the only event that will give focus to the root pane.

So, a more complete check might be to see if a `JPopupMenu` component has been added to the `JRootPane`.

This can be done by using the [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class and replacing the above edit with:

```
if (container != null
&&  SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JPopupMenu.class, container, true).size() != 0)
{
    System.out.println( "JPopupMenu found" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound esoteric, but there are a number of tools that modify Java code on the fly. Think of breakpoints or instrumentation aiming at test coverage reports or profiling.

What you might want to discover is whenever [MouseEvent.isPopupTrigger()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#isPopupTrigger()) returns true, or even better whenever [JPopupMenu.show()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show(java.awt.Component,int,int)) is called.

Unfortunately I have never tried something like this myself, and am wondering whether these links might contain a starting point:

- [Apache Commons BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/)
- [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/)
- [java.lang.instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/instrumentation/index.html)
- [How to instrument java methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659610/how-to-instrument-java-methods)