# Java: Print every method called to console?

Tags: java, debugging

I need to understand a quite large Java project. I browse through it with eclipse and use the call hierarchy and all, but that doesnt get me quite the idea on what is happening when the project runs (it's a webservice).

Is there a possibility to print out every method call with parameters to console? 
Basically something that puts

```
System.out.println("methodName, params: " + param1.toString());
```

in every method for me. 
Some kind of framework that provides that for example?

Comment: Try to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823557/java-logging-method-calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to use [Aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (AOP).

Here is an example that does more or less what you want: [How to use AOP with AspectJ for logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, although the topic seems intimidating at first, I got it all running :)

For anyone else who wants to log their method calls but does not want to go deeper in the whole AOP thing, this is how it worked for me: 
* install AJDT to your eclipse
* convert Java project to AspectJ project
* copy- paste the Aspect code from with this tutorial: http://mathewjhall.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/tracing-java-method-execution-with-aspectj/
* Run project